# How to pass query parameter to http post before query parameter gets lost in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: http, post, asp.net-core-mvc

I want query parameter in HTTP `POST`, but when form is filled up, query parameter is being lost:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ResetPassword(User user)
{
    // bring token
      
    // var token = Request.Query["tokenid"];
    // string stoken = email;
    string token = HttpContext.Request.Query["tokenid"];
    string stoken = token; 
        
    var data = _context.PasswordReset3s
                       .Where(d =>  d.Token ==stoken).FirstOrDefault();
       
    return View();
}
```

Comment: *.... but when form is fieldqury is beging lost* - sorry, but I don't understand what that means. Please edit your question to clarify and correct typos.

Comment: when form is filled up and post request is send query parameter are lost

Comment: How you build the request at client-side? By using the MVC form tag helper? Please post MVC view codes.